# How to parse json value without keys using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to parse json value but there are some value without keys.

like this

```
"geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        127.08373748622218,
                        37.529508099979225
                    ],
                    [
                        127.08355138558433,
                        37.529735847943925
                    ]
                ]
            }
```

Geometry.class

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString
public class Geometry {
    private String type;
    private Coordinate coordinates;
}
```

Coordinate.class

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString
public class Coordinate {
    private List<Double[]> xy;
}
```

then i saw this error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `kr.seoulmaas.ieye.service.dto.path.walk.Coordinate` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 133] (through reference chain: kr.seoulmaas.ieye.service.dto.path.WalkPathResDto["features"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->kr.seoulmaas.ieye.service.dto.path.walk.Feature["geometry"]->kr.seoulmaas.ieye.service.dto.path.walk.Geometry["coordinates"])
```

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example, with hardcoded JSON input, trying to deserialize this JSON input.

Comment: show the `RestTemplate` code

Answer (score 1):

`private Coordinate coordinates;` should be `private List<Coordinate> coordinates;` since it is an array in the JSON, but since the array contains only arrays you need to have a list of lists: `List<List<Double>> coordinates` (suggested by @JBNizet).

Comment: It should actually be a List<List<Double>>, or a List<Double[]> directly. It' not an object, but it's also not an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your data, `coordinates` is a `list` of `list`. So define your Geometry class this way:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString
public class Geometry {
    private String type;
    private List<Coordinate> coordinates;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm dreadfully late.

I solved this problem using by JsonNode.

this is my code.

```java
public class Geometry {
    private String type;
    private JsonNode coordinates;
}
```

Comment: But **how** did you solve it by using JsonArray? It may not be as clear to some as to how you did it. Please update your answer with more details, thanks!

Comment: Oh, Sorry i confused with JsonNode.
I solve this problem with JsonNode.